# Wifi,Bluetooth ,Ethernet not working in Fedora 37,64bit

Tags: fedora, wifi, bluetooth, ethernet

How to connect Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, Ethernet

[image]

Comment: Open a terminal, type 1) `lspci` 2) `lsusb` 3) `dmesg --color=always --level=emerg,crit,err -t` - edit your question and add this info.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.